# How can I add an element to a list with a key value using a useState Record type in React typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object, record, use-state

The structure of my Record type looks like this:

```js
const PEOPLE_MAP_INIT: Record<string, Person[]> = {
        "1": [],
        "2": [],
        "3": []
    };
```

The useState is initialized like this:

```js
const [PEOPLE_MAP, SET_PEOPLE_MAP] = useState<Record<string, Person[]>>(PEOPLE_MAP_INIT);
```

Basically, I am trying to hold a list of "Person objects" corresponding to the string key value which will each hold its own unique list.

I'm trying to add a Person object to the first list in the PEOPLE_MAP from a given master list of Person objects:

```js
SET_PEOPLE_MAP({...PEOPLE_MAP, ["1"]: personList[i]});
```

However, this just gives me type errors. I know somewhere I'm misunderstanding the use of Record types but I'm just not sure how to go about fixing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote the AddPerson function like this and it works fine without any error type

```
const addPerson = () => {

  const newPerson = new Person('Joe', 30);

  const newPeopleMap = {...peopleMap};

  newPeopleMap["1"].push(newPerson);

  setPeopleMap(newPeopleMap);   
};
```

The whole code is here -> https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-wind-8spnv

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, the main point here I think was to create that newPeopleMap, because I tried the .push but on the original peopleMap and it was not updating properly. Again thank you for the answer!